# javascript how to add element dynamically to form tag using button

Tags: javascript, html

i have a html view with form tag, i need to add dynamically text to the form using a button click, the full code is below work well when i remove the `<form>` tag, but when i keep the form tag is doenst work, seems like the page is refreshing and text is disappearing

```
<html>
    <body>
  <form  >
<button onclick="create()">Create Heading</button>

</form>

    <script>
  function create() {
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.textContent = "New Heading!!!";
    h1.setAttribute('class', 'note');
    document.body.appendChild(h1);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the default action:

```js
function create(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //add this
  var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.textContent = "New Heading!!!";
  h1.setAttribute('class', 'note');
  document.body.appendChild(h1);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button onclick="create(event)">Create Heading</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `prevent` default submit behavior with preventDefault()

```
<html>
    <body>
  <form  >
<button onclick="create(e)">Create Heading</button>

</form>

    <script>
  function create(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.textContent = "New Heading!!!";
    h1.setAttribute('class', 'note');
    document.body.appendChild(h1);
  }
</script>
```